# XML data extracted across two classes

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have two classes and the following XML. I do not know how to create objects of Director and Movie out of the following XML. I'd like to use Linq but have tried many things and not sure.

I would like to have all director objects with their ID's and I'd like to have all the movie objects with all their fields.

```
public class Director
{
public int DirectorID;
public string Name;
}

public class Movie
{
public string DirectorID;
public string Genre;
public string Rating;
public string MovieName;
}



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Movie xmlns="http://www.imdb.co.uk" CreationDate="2015-01-25T18:14:33" year="2012" NumberOfMovies="6">
   <DirectorMovie>
      <Director>
         <Name>Ridley Scott</Name>
      </Director>
      <Movie>
         <Genre>Horror</Genre>
         <Rating>8.9</Rating>
         <MovieName>Alien</MovieName>
      </Movie>
      <Movie>
         <Genre>Sci-Fi</Genre>
         <Rating>8.7</Rating>
         <MovieName>Blade Runner</MovieName>
      </Movie>
      <Movie>
         <Genre>Action</Genre>
         <Rating>7.4</Rating>
         <MovieName>Black Hawk Down</MovieName>
      </Movie>
   </DirectorMovie>
   <DirectorMovie>
      <Director>
         <Name>James Cameron</Name>
      </Director>
      <Movie>
         <Genre>Action</Genre>
         <Rating>8.9</Rating>
         <MovieName>Aliens</MovieName>
      </Movie>
      <Movie>
         <Genre>Sci-Fi</Genre>
         <Rating>8.5</Rating>
         <MovieName>Avatar</MovieName>
      </Movie>
      <Movie>
         <Genre>Action</Genre>
         <Rating>8.8</Rating>
         <MovieName>Prometheus</MovieName>
      </Movie>
   </DirectorMovie>
</Movie>
```

Comment: <default-comment>What have you tried so far?</default-comment>

Comment: Where is `DirectorID` in your XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, this will help you with what you wanted- I assume that id is autogenerated.

```
int iID = 1;
        XNamespace xn = "http://www.imdb.co.uk";
        // List of individual directors;
        var list = xeDir.Descendants(xn + "DirectorMovie").Select(item => new Director()
                                                    {
                                                        DirectorID = iID++,
                                                        Name = item.Element(xn + "Director").Element(xn + "Name").Value
                                                    });

        // Dictionary of directors name vs movies list.
        var movList = xeDir.Descendants(xn + "DirectorMovie").
            ToDictionary(dir => dir.Element(xn + "Director").Element(xn + "Name").Value,
                                          dir => dir.Elements(xn + "Movie").
                                              Select(mov => new Movie()
                                          {
                                              Genre = mov.Element(xn + "Genre").Value,
                                              MovieName = mov.Element(xn + "MovieName").Value,
                                              Rating = mov.Element(xn + "Rating").Value,
                                              DirectorID = list.Where(item => item.Name == dir.Element(xn + "Director").Element(xn + "Name").Value).First().DirectorID.ToString()

                                          })
                         );
```

Answer (score 0):

First, be careful as how you define your class. For now, you have created classes that have only public attributes, which is probably not something you want to do. Check how to create [properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) and [auto-implemented properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx).

Then, in terms of parsing, it's quite straightforward using Linq to XML (the code has not been tested in anyway and is far from complete, use as something to get started):

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlData);

var movieElement = doc.Element("Movie")
                        .Elements("DirectorMovie")
                        .Elements("Movie")
                        .Select(x => new Movie{
                            DirectorId = GetDirectorIdFromName(x.Parent.Element("Director").Element("Name").Value),
                            Genre = x.Element("Genre").Value
                        });
```